# AppleScript to move file to /Library

Tags: terminal, applescript, install

I need to run a simple command like this:

```
do shell script "sudo cp -r /Users/me/file.plugin /Library/My-Plug-Ins" with administrator privileges
```

However I get "operation not permitted", with or withou sudo.

Error:

```
error "cp: /Users/me/file.plugin: unable to copy extended attributes to /Library/My-Plug-Ins/file.plugin: Operation not permitted
cp: /Users/me/file.plugin: Operation not permitted" number 1
```

I know the file exists and I know I can copy it with c++ code; however, I want something that will look more "seamless" and not have an issue so I'd prefer applescript or something more professional than a terminal window?

Currently on MacOs Monterey

Comment: In what context are you running this AppleScript? (i.e. how is this script being launched and run?) Given that it's shell script, any reason you're not just using shell script? It's likely to be a security issue with the root-level Library. Could you not move the plug-in to the user Library instead? Also, `man cp` doesn't list an -r flag, but an -R flag.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks. Currently I have tried a few ways... I have run it as script and exported as application (given the application full disk access). I have created a script file to run but I cannot get this script file to run with sudo with a password popup to be more of a seamless (commercial) looking. From terminal it works running from sudo, I'd like to avoid this which is why I used Applescript. Also ran the bash script from applescript with administrator privileges. No luck...

Comment: AppleScript is considerably 'higher up' the order of things than shell scripting. It's likely that you need to give Full Disk Access to AppleEvents or Script Editor or some other process. Is this supposed to be some sort of installer?

Comment: @benwiggy yes I'd like it to install a file for my application. When I export the script as an application and grant full access it still doesn't work. Similary ScriptEditor having access also doesn't work...

Comment: Are you intending that this script should work on any computer for other users, or just for you on yours? Because there are prescribed (and proscribed!) methods for the former.

Comment: If you think there is a better way for the former. I'm all ears. I am right now focusing on MacOs. I currently wrote a c++ app to "install" file (ie: move it to correct folder in Library) but it requires a terminal for sudo password. I feel like there is a correct/easier way to do this I am missing.

Comment: The usual way is to create a .pkg file for the Installer app to run.

Comment: @Mockman I have close the Stackoverflow post. I think the location here made more sense. My apologies.

Comment: Color me surprised, but the cp error didn't lie; it seems to be the *reading* that is the problem, not the writing. SIP or Gatekeeper or somesuch? Doing everything from (say) `/Users/Shared/` then writes to `/Library/My/` fine. I could not even find the process to allow-list (cp, sh, Script Editor, bash, …) to let it read from `/Users/yourhome/my.plugin`. "Comments are not for conversation" yes, yes, but I'd recommend packaging it in [Packages.app](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html), or Apple's Xcode or PackageMaker.

Comment: @JoelReid Thanks so much for looking into this... I think you're right, I might try a totally different route. If you write an answer I am happy to mark as correct, even if it is quite simply your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm concerned this question has become an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/209096), where diagnosing errors and… "AppleScript app to home directory rights" puzzles may work and solve the problem of the moment, but would not actually then be portable, reliable, nor even advisable.

If we generalize the question to "How do I install things from an AppleScript," the best generalized answer is probably, "do not."

Please consider packing up the file into a .dmg, with an alias (aka "shortcut" or, here, a symbolic link with the absolute path) to the destination folder, so end users can install by drag-and-drop and be automatically prompted for write privileges as needed.

Or best, create a installer flat package .pkg file to install everything needed.

Comment: I create packages in [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html). I've also had success with macOS-Installer-Builder ([github](https://github.com/KosalaHerath/macos-installer-builder), [writeup](https://medium.com/swlh/the-easiest-way-to-build-macos-installer-for-your-application-34a11dd087440)).